# how can i get product in a custom module

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php, bundled-product, ce-1.8.1.0

I have a custom module for product view page and it does the exact functions that does by product view page. In default product view page, a product is getting  and load like this

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

Since I am using my own custom module, instead of using getProduct() method, i am using

```
<?php 
     $id = 44;
     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
?>
```

Due to this, I couldn't do the add to cart functionality for my product.When I do console, it says 'productId' is not defined. 
How can I add my product to cart as default case? what should i do for that...  please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

hey You ca try below code

```
$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

// Load product
$my_product_sku = 'YOUR SKU';        
$my_product_id  = $product_model->getIdBySku($my_product_sku);
$my_product     = $product_model->load($my_product_id);

$qty_value = 13;

// Add to cart (?)
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($my_product, array('qty' => $qty_value));
$cart->save();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. how should be my form element in order to use this code?

Comment: I didn't get you please Explain me in detal.

Comment: this is the default product view page's form element..  <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>. i used this in my page.but the action field is empty then. why it happends like this?

Comment: action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"
try this one

Comment: it is not working. i think this problem causes because I am not usig getProduct(). I have registered my product after loading the product.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12003/discussion-between-keyul-shah-and-rajeevktomy)

Comment: yes that is true if you not get product then how can you add that product.

Comment: i am getting product. i am using a custom function which is defined in my block of my module in order to load the product. function returns the id of product and i am loading product in my phtml page using Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load() method

Comment: is it good if you can use Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($YourId);

Comment: eventhough my module act as product view page, it does not use any of the block of default product view page.

Comment: what is the difference between those two methods?

Comment: for more details refer my blog you got all understanding

http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/difference-between-magegetsingleton-and-magegetmodel-in-magento/

Comment: I have give you in above message

Comment: i have loaded using above mentioned method. but the thing is that all are working perfectly. But form action is still empty and now also add to cart is not working. Can you tell me, where should i add your code?

Comment: Please trace you got the product details or not if yes then it will work .

I also check in 
catlog/prodcut/list.phtml file


<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart-options" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

Comment: i have used this button before.<button type="button" title="<?php echo 'ordernow' ?>" id="international_btn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">--> . but it redirected to the same page before. i have used your code now. but output is this.<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart-options" onclick="setLocation('')"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>. setLocation() is emplty here and here also it redirected to the same page

Comment: productAddToCartForm.submit(this). i think the problem is here. when i checked this code, it uses a productId variable. but in my page. i didnt define this productId variable. I examined product.js file and from there, i understood that, i need to configure my prdouct in order to set the productId. Do you know how to  set this ?

Comment: no I have no idea for that